# Function "poly_distance" not implemented - how to resolve?

Tags: postgresql, spatial, spatial-query

I have PG 9.5.2 under Windows 64-bit.

```
select polygon '((-1,0),(0,1),(1,0))' <-> polygon '((0,0),(1,1),(2,0))'
```

Returns:

> Function "poly_distance" not implemented

I've done a Google search, but haven't found anything useful on how to resolve this.

Comment: Just to know: what is the "distance between two polygons"? Mathematically?

Comment: That's right. It works for other shapes (even mixed).

Comment: I just can not imagine: distance between the nearest points? between weighted centers? between average coordinates?

Comment: Between nearest points. I read up on how it's done. It's ugly. They usually just measure the distance between ALL points and the shortest is the answer (bounding boxes apply).